# Can I run docker system prune -a without downtime

Tags: docker

I want to execute `docker system prune -a` to clean up space. Could someone please tell me if I can execute this command without `docker-compose down` (without removing the containers and downtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/ says:

> Remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes.

About -a option it says:

> Remove all unused images not just dangling ones

So for sure this command does not produce a downtime.
You can execute it without "docker-compose down".